# jQuery: Offset position with mouse event

Tags: jquery, offset, mousemove

I'm currently coding a block breaker as a jQuery exercise, and I have a problem with my racket which change position when I leave the playfield on the left.

I'm new with all the mouse events, and I tried a lot of solutions and ideas found here on stackoverflow or on the internet, even changing my whole code, but the only way I found to have a correct position is to make a condition with the mouseleave event to correct the offset. But I don't like it, because it causes more position problems if the mouse is above or under the playfield that I didn't have before doing that.

It's probably the second part of this that don't work, but I don't see how to change it.

```
racket.left = Math.min(canvasWidth - racket.width, Math.max(2, e.offsetX));
```

See the JSFiddle to see what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/Shilok/29wu6gj8/1/

I want the same behaviour than on the right: when the racket touches either side and the mouse is out of the playfield, the racket stays where it is (sticked on the side!)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a couple more thing

1. The offsetX of the event you use depends on which element you are hovering over. You should normalize that by using `pageX` instead which always return the left in relation to the whole document.
2. You should wrap your `Math.min` in a `Math.max` to not allow it to go below 0.
3. You need to take into account the offset of the `.canvas` itself.
4. You should also recalculate the offset on the `resize` event of the window

```js
var canvasWidth, racket, canvasOffset;

$(document).ready(init);

function init() {
  $(window).resize(calculate).trigger('resize');
  $(window).on('mousemove', moveRacket);
}

function calculate() {
  canvasWidth = $('.canvas').width();
  racket = {
    width: $(".racket").width()
  };
  canvasOffset = $('.canvas').offset()
}

function moveRacket(e) {
  var minLeft = Math.max(0, e.pageX - canvasOffset.left - racket.width / 2),
    maxLeft = canvasWidth - racket.width;

  racket.left = Math.max(Math.min(maxLeft, minLeft), 0);
  $('.racket').css('left', racket.left + 'px');
}
```

```css
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.canvas {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
}

.racket {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 14px;
  bottom: 12px;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="canvas">
  <div class="racket"></div>
</div>
```

---

Updated fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/0p9ke2wa/